# Python script runs from terminal, but not crontab. Using absolute paths but to no avail

Tags: python, bash, cron, centos7

This is my crontab.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/home1/<user>/.pyenv/shims:/home1/<user>/.pyenv/bin:/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/nhnkrb5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home1/<user>/.local/bin:/home1/<user>/bin
HOME=/home1/<user>


# Do something
0 1 * * * /home1/<user>/.pyenv/shims/python /home1/<user>/folder/myscript.py >> /home1/<user>/folder/$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").log 2>&1
```

It runs perfectly from the terminal no matter where I execute it from. I have tried every answer on this page, and my cron doesn't return any errors.
https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/why-crontab-scripts-are-not-working

I have also checked that my `$PATH` the cron runs from is identical to the one in my bash. Checked using `* * * * * env > /tmp/env.txt`

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: According to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/29582/77928), you need to escape the `%` symbol.

Comment: @user000001 thanks, I have escaped the `%` but unfortunately it still doesn't work.

Comment: @Yuu: Change at the end to: `...myscript.py 2>&1 >>  /tmp/myscript.log`. Read the log if any.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to add the python header at line 1 to your main script. For example if your main script file is `app.py` then it's content can be following:

```sh
!#/home1/<user>/.pyenv/shims/python

# Here goes your Python Script.
```

and then

```sh
$ chmod +x app.py
```

Now you can add

```sh
# Do something
0 1 * * * /home1/<user>/folder/myscript.py >> /home1/<user>/folder/$(date "+%Y.%m.%d-%H.%M.%S").log 2>&1
```

I ran into the same problem, script working when I am running manually but didn't work with `crontab`. This method worked.